# Unable to run chromedriver using selenium in Python in aws cloud9

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, selenium-webdriver, aws-cloud9

After I install selenium, chrome, and chromedriver to aws cloud9, I tried to execute chromedriver. But PATH error occurred.

I checked chromedriver path is correct. And I don't know why this error happened.

```sh
aws:~/environment/seleniumTest $ ll /home/ec2-user/environment/seleniumTest/chromedriver
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user 8496784 Sep 13  2018 /home/ec2-user/environment/seleniumTest/chromedriver
```

Are there any solutions to solve this problem?

My steps is as below,

1.install selenium
pip install selenium -t ./

2.install chrome
curl https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash

3.download chromedriver
curl -SL https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/chromedriver_linux64.zip > chromedriver.zip
unzip chromedriver.zip

4.Execute Python code as below

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/ec2-use/environment/seleniumTest/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

    return(0)
```

I got "'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH" error.

```
Response
{
    "errorMessage": "Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home\n",
    "errorType": "WebDriverException",
    "stackTrace": [
        [
            "/var/task/seleniumTest/lambda_function.py",
            9,
            "lambda_handler",
            "driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/ec2-use/environment/seleniumTest/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)"
        ],
        [
            "/var/task/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py",
            73,
            "__init__",
            "self.service.start()"
        ],
        [
            "/var/task/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
            83,
            "start",
            "os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)"
        ]
    ]
}

Function Logs
Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
: WebDriverException
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/seleniumTest/lambda_function.py", line 9, in lambda_handler
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/ec2-use/environment/seleniumTest/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
  File "/var/task/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/var/task/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're specifying the executable_path for Chromedriver properly, I think the below should work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/ec2-user/environment/seleniumTest/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

    return(0)
```

Comment: Thanks the comment, but the error message is same. Although I added "executable_path=" , cloud9 can't recognize the chromedriver  path.

Comment: ah - are you sure the path is correct? Should it be:

/home/ec2-user/environment/seleniumTest/chromedriver

instead of ec2-use?

Comment: Yes. As I tried many ways, I wrote "ec2-use" version in the question, I'm sorry. I tried "/home/ec2-user/environment/seleniumTest/chromedriver" version, but the same error occurred.